# How to create a Custom Drawer Stateful Widget from the given code?

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer, flutter-layout, statefulwidget, flutter-listview

I have solved the previous issue based on an existing solution to existing question.

[I want to change the color of CustomListTile which is child of ListView when onTap is clicked, and setting other children color into default one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753198/i-want-to-change-the-color-of-customlisttile-which-is-child-of-listview-when-ont)

#### I am still facing problem in creating a Stateful Widget for the Drawer.

Here is Github link to project: https://github.com/Aaklii/flutter_app

```
drawer: buildDrawer(context),
```

#### I want to give more features to drawer item in a later stage so I want to create a Stateful Widget but this code is not working:

```
class ListDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
    List<ListClass> listOjects;
    ListDrawer({this.listOjects});
    @override
    _ListDrawerState createState() => _ListDrawerState();
  }

  class _ListDrawerState extends State<ListDrawer> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.listOjects.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return CustomListTile(
                      listObject: widget.listOjects[index],
  //                    isSelected:
  //                    selectedIndex != null && selectedIndex == index
  //                        ? true
  //                        : false,
                      index: index,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

#### So I am currently using buildDrawer()

```
Drawer buildDrawer(BuildContext context) {
return Drawer(
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: listOjects.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      onSelected(index);
                    });
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: CustomListTile(
                    listObject: listOjects[index],
                    isSelected:
                        selectedIndex != null && selectedIndex == index
                            ? true
                            : false,
                    index: index,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

Comment: i think here is too much code and text

Comment: @Eugene I have shortened the question. Need solution only for the drawer part of flutter app.